# how to send dropdownlist selectedvalue as postback argument in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a server control that works with `IPostBackEventHandler`.

And inside that control, I have a DropDownList.

And this DropDownList should raise postback event with it's argument.

```
DropDownList _ddl = new DropDownList();
_ddl.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onchange.ToString()
    , this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "this.value"));
```

What I am trying to do is to get the selected value of DropDownList on postback.

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
}
```

When I receive from the RaisePostBackEvents, I only get "this.value". Not the selected value from DropDownList.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal assign `ID` to `_ddl` and pass it as argument in `GetPostBackEventReference`.

```
DropDownList _ddl = new DropDownList();
_ddl.ID = "MyDropDownList";
_ddl.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onchange.ToString()
    , this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, _ddl.ID));
```

Then in `RaisePostBackEvent` you need to find your control by its `ID` provided in `eventArgument` and in that way get the `SelectedValue`.

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    DropDownList _ddl = FindControl(eventArgument) as DropDownList;
    if (_ddl == null) return;

    string selectedValue = _ddl.SelectedValue;
    // do whatever you need with value
}
```

Why you cannot use JavaScript `this.value`? There is no support for JavaScript calls and if you look at generated HTML you will see:

```
__doPostBack('ctl02','MyDropDownList');
```

Where `__doPostBack` function is following:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

As you can see  the `recipient` parameter is equal to `ctl02` which is `UniqueID` of the user control. It got there when you passed `this` in `GetPostBackEventReference` call. `eventArgument` value is assigned to `__EVENTARGUMENT` hidden field and then submitted with form. This is a second parameter of `GetPostBackEventReference` call.

So second paratemer of `GetPostBackEventReference` is always encoded as string by internal class  `System.Web.UI.Util.QuoteJScriptString` method.